# monthly created account of last 12 months

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table of accounts, in wich a column named "dateCreation" is the date of the creation of the account.

I would like to get all created account the last 12 months, but sometimes there is no account created duing 2 months or more. For theses months i vould like mysql return 0. My request works fine (i get it here on stackoverflow):

```
 SELECT  customers.dateCreation, Months.id AS `month`, Months.mois, COUNT(customers.dateCreation) AS `count`
FROM 
(
  SELECT 1 as ID, 'Janvier' as mois UNION SELECT 2 as ID, 'Février' as mois UNION  SELECT 3 as ID, 'Mars' as mois UNION SELECT 4 as ID, 'Avril' as mois 
  UNION  
  SELECT 5 as ID, 'Mai' as mois UNION SELECT 6 as ID, 'Juin' as mois UNION SELECT 7 as ID, 'Juillet' as mois UNION SELECT 8 as ID , 'Aout' as mois
  UNION  
  SELECT 9 as ID, 'Septembre' as mois UNION SELECT 10 as ID, 'Octobre' as mois UNION SELECT 11 as ID, 'Novembre' as mois UNION SELECT 12 as ID, 'Decembre' as mois
) as Months
LEFT JOIN customers on Months.id=month(customers.dateCreation) AND dateCreation BETWEEN Date_add(Now(),interval - 12 month) AND NOW()
GROUP BY Months.id
ORDER BY Months.id ASC
```

But it returns something like that:

```
    ID    |    Count
    1     |      0
    2     |      0
    3     |      0
    4     |      0
    5     |      8
    6     |      1
    7     |      0
    8     |      1
    9     |      0
    10    |      7
    11    |      0
    12    |      4
```

But we're on September, so i would like the first month is October

here is a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edfeb/1

Answer (score 3):

Modify your order to:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN Months.id > MONTH(NOW()) -- check if the month is after the current 
       THEN 0                        -- order by months after the current first
       ELSE 1                        -- and then by the months up to the current 
  END,
  Months.id ASC
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edfeb/7/0)

Comment: @Alexking2005: Added more explanation

Comment: @Alexking2005 it seems quite self-explanatory. What are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this by replacing left join:

```
LEFT JOIN customers ON Months.id=MONTH(customers.dateCreation) 
    AND dateCreation BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL - 12 MONTH) AND CURDATE()
```